# Swift: Data is not being stored in variable when passing through VC

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to store the name of a map pin in a variable, then display it on a label on my second VC.

Currently, this is what I've got.

**FirstVC.swift**

```
//Perform segue when callout has been tapped
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {

     self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showAnnotationInfo", sender:view)

        }


func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {

    print("Annotation selected")

    if let annotation = view.annotation as? POIAnnotations {
        print("Your annotation title is: \(annotation.title!)")

        // Instantiate ShopDetailViewController
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let destVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "shopDetailVC") as! ShopDetailViewController

        destVC.shopNameData = annotation.title!
        print("Shop name data has the value: \(destVC.shopNameData)")

    }
}
```

**ShopDetailViewController.swift**

```
class ShopDetailViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var shopName: UILabel!

var shopNameData = "data"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.shopName.text = self.shopNameData
    print(shopNameData)

  }

}
```

What is happening is, when I attempt to store `annotation.title` in `shopNameData`, there is no problem.

However, when I click on the annotation, the data from `annotation.title` is no longer stored in `shopNameData` and simply displays the default data.

[image]

I'm not sure where I've gone wrong here.

**EDIT**

I've included where I present `ShopDetailViewController`.

Comment: There is no code of navigation or present?

Comment: How are you presenting `ShopDetailViewController`? a sotryboard segue from IB or performSegue from code?

Comment: @WarifAkhandRishi check edit.

Answer (score 2):

You are simply creating an instance of the `ShopDetailViewController`, setting the value and then doing nothing with it. The instance of `ShopDetailViewController` that you created goes out of scope and gets deallocated.

How are you presenting the `ShopDetailViewController`? Are you using a segue? If you are then you should override the `prepareForSegue()` method where you will get an instantiated version of the `ShopDetailViewController` which will be presented and not go out of scope and then simply set the `shopNameData` property in there.

EDIT:

Thanks for clarifying the way you are presenting the view controller. So to answer you comment:

You need to go to `FirstVC` and add something like the following code:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if let viewController = segue.destination as? ShopDetailViewController,
        let annotationView = sender as? MKAnnotationView,
        let annotation = annotationView.annotation as? POIAnnotations {

        viewController.shopNameData = annotation.title
    }
}
```

Then after that you can just remove the code in your `func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView)` method and keep the code in your `func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl)` method.

This way you are simply calling present and passing the MKAnnotationView through as the sender, then pulling out the relevant information when the segue is preparing to present your view controller. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I've added where I present the second VC. How do I override it?

Comment: I've updated my answer to explain a bit more now you have added information about how the VC is being presented.

Comment: I'm getting an error stating value of type 'MKAnnotationView has no member 'title'.

Comment: Oops sorry, I wrote `annotationView.title` instead of `annotation.title`. Crucial session there though, never blindly copy and paste code from stack overflow ;)

Comment: Ah, thanks! But label still seems to be displaying the default data.

Comment: My suggestion would be to put a breakpoint in the `prepareForSegue()` method to see if it's being called correctly and the logic is being ran as expected. I'm having to guess a bit now as I can't see the rest of your code to replicate it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131272/discussion-between-daanyyaal-and-dlbuckley).

Answer (score 0):

Override prepare for segue method like so:

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if (let view = sender as! MKAnnotationView) && (segue.identifier == "showAnnotationInfo") {
           if annotation = view.annotation as? POIAnnotation {
              let destVC = segue.destination as! ShopDetailViewController
              destVC.shopNameData = annotation.title!
           }
        }
    }
```